# Why is payload of packet wrong when I use pcap_loop to capture packets

Tags: linux

I write a libpcap program running on server end, for testing TCP packet payload between server and client. The packets exchanged between server and client are:Client connects to server and then send 5 bytes of "hello". Finally, server sends 12 bytes of "hello client" back to client. Following is my program to inspect packet content, mainly by `pcap_loop`. But I don't know why the length of captured packet is always 74(14+20+20+20) and payload content is wrong. I use `x/100xb` to inspect memory the packet and **IP adderss and port are right**. The memory of payload is:

payload(20 bytes)

> 0x7ffff75d70bc:   0x02    0x04    0x05    0x64    0x04    0x02    0x08    0x0a
>   0x7ffff75d70c4:   0x00    0x32    0xfe    0x5e    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00
>   0x7ffff75d70cc:   0x01    0x03    0x03    0x07

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pcap.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void processPacket(u_char *args, const struct pcap_pkthdr *header,                                                         
                   const u_char *packet);


int main(void)
{
    char dev[] = "eth1";
    char errBuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
    char str[] = "port 40002";
    int cnt = 5; // count of packtes
    int promisc = 1;
    int to_ms = 1000 * 1000;
    int ret;
    pcap_t *handle;
    pcap_handler callback = processPacket;
    struct bpf_program fp;

    handle = pcap_open_live(dev, 1536, promisc, to_ms, errBuf);
    if (!handle) {
        exit(-1);
    }

    // set filter
    ret = pcap_compile(handle, &fp, str, 0, 0);
    if (ret < 0) {
        exit(-1);
    }
    ret = pcap_setfilter(handle, &fp);
    if (ret < 0) {
        exit(-1);
    }

    printf("start capture\n");

    // capture in loop
    pcap_loop(handle, 5, callback, NULL);

    return 0;
}

// callback in pcap_loop
void processPacket(u_char *args, const struct pcap_pkthdr *header,             
                   const u_char *packet)
{


}
```